# Dstat network metrics

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Could anybody say about dstat's network metrics (*`dstat -n`*)?
Is it Bytes or Bits?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Bytes.. at least from version .3.  from changelog:

- 0.3

  - Added load stats (-l)
  - Added memory stats (-m)
  - Output now fits into space and adds unit
  - Converted all values to bytes

interestingly.. in 0.7.2svn they added bits option

- 0.7.2svn - ... - release 03/09/2010

  - ...
  - Added new --bits option to force bit-values on screen (Scott Baker)

https://github.com/dagwieers/dstat/blob/master/ChangeLog

Answer (score 4):

I confirmed that the unit for network metric is **`Bytes/sec`**

**Methodology:**
I ran some network I/O traffic and measured with `dstat`

```
[root@centos72_base ~]# dstat --full
You did not select any stats, using -cdngy by default.
-------cpu0-usage--------------cpu1-usage------ --dsk/sda-- net/eno1677 ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq:usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
  4   0  96   0   0   0:  1   0  99   0   0   0|   0     0 |1205k 9874B|   0     0 | 562   601 
  4   0  96   0   0   0:  0   0 100   0   0   0|   0     0 |1206k   10k|   0     0 | 529   656 
  4   1  95   0   0   0:  4   0  96   0   0   0|   0     0 |1206k   10k|   0     0 | 580   712 
  3   0  97   0   0   0:  2   0  98   0   0   0|   0     0 |1207k   10k|   0     0 | 506   615
```

At steady state, I was averaging `1206k`. I outputted `dtsat` to CSV to see the full numbers and got the full values such as `1234196`.

Next, I got network metrics using `ifconfig`.

```
[cyc@centos72_base one_forward]$ ifconfig; sleep 1; ifconfig; sleep 1; ifconfig
        RX packets 18500852  bytes 42118560051 (39.2 GiB)
        ...
        RX packets 18501061  bytes 42119793977 (39.2 GiB)
        ...
        RX packets 18501286  bytes 42121029469 (39.2 GiB)
```

`ifconfig` clearly states network metrics are in GigaBytes. Calculating the difference between two successive seconds: `42119793977 - 42118560051 = 1233926`. `1233926 Bytes/sec` from `ifconfig` closely matches `1234196` from `dstat`. So `dstat` is outputting in **`Bytes/sec`**

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it is bytes, since the output shows `B`, bits would be `b`:

```
-net/total-
 recv  send
   0     0 
2376B  725B
1523B  180B
```

However, nothing in the manual confirms this.

Comment: I think so. I output the results to a text file and compare the values in "k" and "M" and in "B" (do -output [filename], all fields are in the same unit). If "M" means "MB", and "k" means "kB", the value in the "B" field is consistent with "Byte" other than "bit". I do not think the designer of "dstat" will use "bit" as the unit. That is just not intuitive and straightforward.

Comment: The confusion here happens because when we use dstat with --output there is not K, M and B anymore.